# How to debug MS Access Run-time error 2046?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Our office uses MS access for storing patient's data and printing results. We've been using it for almost 2 years now. Suddenly, I have come across an error "Run-time error '2046'; The command or action 'RecordsGoToNew' isn't available now.

I tried to debug it and I can't find the error.

Here's the code it leads to when clicked on debug button:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
If Not Me.NewRecord Then
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
End If
End Sub
```

Thank you so much for answering!

Comment: Is the database in the same file, or is it split with the database as external file / sql server ? Can you return to a previous version of the file and check if the error occours there as well ? Also, what is the name of the table where you try to add a new record ?

Comment: The database might be read-only. Possible reasons: changes in folder/file permissions, corruption (?), "something went wrong". -- Check if you can edit data directly in tables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem in mentioned code the `load sub` structure is correct you need to follow code debug step by step to see where is the error exactly, try to simplify your code just try, to replace `acCmdRecordsGoToNew` with following

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```